# cold water coming out of hot water inlet (water heater)

Tags: water, pipe, heater

The hot water heater suddenly stopped heating the water that runs to the house.

I'm visiting Puerto Rico tending to my elderly parents and their hot water heater suddenly stopped working.

I removed the hot water heater and took it to the manufacturer, and they found nothing wrong with it.  They did exchange a spring inside the WH so that it could work with less pressure since that is what they thought the problem was. They mentioned that it could be due to a recent installation of a shower wand.

I brought it back to the house and that did not fix the issue.

The hot water is getting heated because I tested it prior to attaching it, but as soon as I attach it to the pipe (hot water inlet) the water does not come out hot in the house.

I noticed that the inlet pipe is shooting water out so it makes sense that if the water heater is shooting hot water in but the inlet pipe is shooting cold water out,the water is just crashing.  The cold water outlet pipe is working as it should, so it's not that we have the lines confused.

My question is, why would there be water coming out of the inlet pipe?

I've already done all the trouble shooting suggestions

Comment: Your description is confusing.  "I noticed that the inlet pipe is shooting water out so it makes sense that if the water heater is shooting hot water in but the inlet pipe is shooting cold water out,the water is just crashing. "   ?   Maybe a picture of the unit?

Comment: Yes, a picture of the plumbing set up would be helpful. Also, do you get _any_ water out of the hot water taps in the house, or do you just get cold water from both sides?

Comment: `why would there be water coming out of the inlet pipe?` ... maybe one of the taps in the house has both hot and cold turned on and the tap itself is plugged somehow ... nothing to do with the heater

Comment: I'm confused by all these inlets and outlets.

Comment: My apologies. Let me start over.  The WH has one hose entry for the cold water that comes from the street, I attach one end of the hose to the WH and the other end to the spout on the wall that shoots city water into the house.   The WH has a second hose entry where that cold water would now be coming out hot. I attach a second hose there and the other end to the pipe that feeds the water to the whole house.   The problem is, that THAT pipe that is supposed to receive the now hot water from the WH and shoot it into the faucets of the house, is shooting water out with pressure.